# Why don't the humans in Star Trek have a longer lifespan than established in canon?

Tags: star-trek

One thing that intrigues me about Star Trek is that humans have a life expectancy of 120 years, people who reach that age are represented as quite old, extremely wrinkled skin, with slower locomotion, etc.

Unlike, for example, the Vulcans, who have a life expectancy of 200 years, where in several episodes, Vulcans with more than a century of age are shown maintaining a healthier body than a human of the same age or a Klingon, where in DS9 we see in an episode where we have Klingons who are nearly 150 years old going into battle.

I think that an expectation of 120 years for humans is very low, the Federation has a very advanced technology in general and specifically the medical one, with the eradication of many genetic diseases, genetic improvements can be made and we have a brain and genetic mapping extremely advanced.

For example, the technology of teleportation and matter synthesizer could be used to create artificial organs compatible with the individual, using the teleportation buffer pattern, with zero risk of rejection.

Comment: Of the potential life extenders, genetic mapping and tweaking seems to be a controversial hot topic in the Federation. You remove a genetic disposition for diabetes here, a genetic marker for demeaning plebney there and suddenly you have Khan Noonien Singh.  The other tech solutions are fair game, I reckon, and make the question valid.

Comment: I can’t find this directly addressed in any works, but I also think the ban on genetic modification is key. I’ve written an answer below but it is a bit speculative, as there’s not much to go on.

Answer (score 6):

**You are working on the assumption that medical advance increases the maximum lifespan of humans while experience has proven that, so far, it increases the average lifespan.**

While that is a road the writers may have taken they did not and there is no contradiction in canon for it not being that way.

Let's start by stating the obvious, Star Trek is a work of fiction. As such, the writers are free to explore the topics they like however they like.

If you review medical history for the last 2000 years, you'll find documented cases of people reaching and going beyond 100 years of age. That is, in fact, quite similar to the maximum age we achieve today, even with all the different medical advances on the last 20 centuries.

Life expectancy at birth in ancient rome was 25 years, now it is 72 years world wide. The introduction of modern medicine did miracles to increase it, specially after 1900, however it did not significantly change the maximum age.

Of course you can explore whatever you like in a work of fiction, but based on our current experience, in reality, the depiction of Star Trek (where more people tend to live until they are very old) is closer to reality than what you are proposing.

Comment: In fact, the primary reason that the "average" life expectancy for most of human history was around 35 was the extremely high infant mortality rate that was eventually slashed to near-nothingness by the rise of modern medicine and treatment and prevention for childhood killers like tuberculosis, polio, and pneumonia. E.g. see [here](https://learn.age-up.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-human-longevity/). If and when an ancient person reached 20 (which was a big if!), the chance of them reaching 40 was excellent and 60 not too bad. Ancient histories are full of people in their 50's and 60's.

Comment: While the infant mortality thing is true, even compared with their contemporaries in the past century, people sure look younger at a given adult age. Medicine/dentistry and nutrition are pointed to but I have another one: people were exposed to a lot more carbon monoxide and other combustion products from indoor flames. Wallpaper is because walls would become sooty -- think  what that soot and other stuff was doing to human bodies. Outdoor air quality is better now also.

Comment: Manual labor also wears out the body, @releseabe. A lot of construction workers, HVAC employees, etc. look a _lot_ older than they are because of the work they do. Combine that with poorer health care and less knowledge 100 years ago, and you'll end up with people generally _looking_ older. Remember the fitness craze really only started in the 1970s (give or take a bit).

Comment: Also, the use of alcohol was  higher. I spoke to a guy who was born probably in the 1930s and his dad maybe late 19th century or early 20th. The guy told me there was no reading or taking extension classes -- just work all day and then start drinking (or continue drinking since it occurred at work often). This was part of why Prohibition had support -- alcohol use really sounds like it was hard on users and their families. Prohibition failed, but there were good reasons to attempt to do something.

Answer (score 3):

### The ban on genetic enhancement likely prevents this

An in-universe answer is that genetic extension of the human lifespan is illegal because of the Federation’s strict prohibition of genetic enhancement. They take this very seriously, upholding a ban that dates back to the 22nd century or earlier, following the Eugenics Wars.

While we’ve generally seen this in terms of direct “enhancement” of physical and mental capabilities, the ban seems to include anything beyond the treatment of genetic medical conditions. Even in McCoy’s era, the ban was strict enough that the discovery of a Starfleet officer who was a member of a species who practiced genetic modification meant their swift arrest. (See the first season of *Strange New Worlds*.) This stance persists well into the 24th century, as seen by the attitude towards Julian Bashir and his parents. (See especially the *Deep Space 9* episode “Doctor Bashir, I Presume”.) It was also a source of contention between the Federation and some of its enemies, including the Dominion and, much earlier, the Suliban.

Notably this hasn’t been addressed in media set after the 23rd century, and we don’t know how long humans live in the 32nd century depicted in *Discovery*. So the ban may still be in place.

It’s not much of a stretch to imagine that without the allowance of genetic modification, even with the other advanced medical technology of the Federation, human lifespans can only be extended so far. Aging is complicated, but is thought to be influenced by both external and genetic factors, so it’s plausible that the Federation have done as much as they can without going down the path to a second Eugenics War.

Comment: I think traveling thousands of times light speed and transporters are harder problems than life extension -- the first two (as envisaged in ST) are probably not just impossible but pretty much known to be so; people are working right now on life extension and probably billions are being invested in. The amount being spent on warp drive I doubt is ten million -- could be wrong, but anyway, far less likely than life extension although I do think it is a hard problem that many are overly optimistic about because indeed ageing is complex.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the technological advances in various areas would translate into biotech advances that would mean practically immortal superhumans -- not just living millennia but being many times stronger and smarter and perhaps good-looking in ways that are hard to imagine: no human on the planet 150 years ago came close to a supermodel or a movie star; what would be the equivalent of that -- some human who made the supermodel of today look plain or even ugly?

But would viewers be able to relate to such characters? Note that the genetically-enhanced followers of Khan were the bad guys, arrogant and clearly holding normal humans (including the viewers who would have been their contemporaries roughly) in contempt to the point where they were extremely dangerous to "normals" -- they ended up living in squalor on an awful planet, adequately punished for their hubris.

So I strongly think that the limited concessions, like McCoy living to 130 or so, were a compromise between realistic biotech advances commensurate with warp drive and transporter/replicator tech and the perceived alienation towards god-like characters.

I read a science fiction story in the late 1980s or early 1990s wherein only children could benefit from medical advances which resulted in immortality -- adults did not. In this story, one father physically attacked and tried to kill his own son and in general and not surprisingly, this medical treatment caused a giant generational rift.

The same sort of rift between viewers and human ST characters I am sure was the expected result. Again, there is no spinoff devoted to the adventures of Khan's followers or the Q for that matter.

Related to this, the final lines in the immortal human episode from STOS (Requiem for Methuselah) has him ageing normally, devoting his remaining years to helping humanity.

Comment: As a paleontologist, I would like to point out that immortality may be good for individuals, but it is not necessarily good for species, which must adapt to changing conditions. And immortality has its downside for individuals. I wince at the thought of working forever for the same immortal supervisor.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron: I have read that from evolutionary biologists but it sounds kind of paradoxical, right? If a species achieved immortality, it does not need to adapt any further.

Comment: The universe continues to change, but a static species does not. For example, what happens to an unchanging species when their sun becomes brighter or dimmer? Or a new parasite arrives on their planet, or a new pathogenic bacterium evolves?